# clear html form data using php or javascript

Tags: php, html, post, forms, http-post

I've got kind of a situation here : I have the following form :

```
<form action="sample.php" id="searchform" method="post">
<input type="text" id="key_words" name="key_words" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['key_words']) ? $_POST['key_words'] : '' ?>"style="width:377px;">
<input type="text" name="minimum_price" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['minimum_price']) ? $_POST['minimum_price'] : '' ?>">
<input type="text" name="maximum_price" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['maximum_price']) ? $_POST['maximum_price'] : '' ?>">
```

I'm using the php script in value because i need to keep the value in text box persistent. So, now i need to clear the values in text box when i click a button:

```
<button type="reset" value="clear" onclick="clearform()">Clear</button>
```

I've tried a few things and failed. Help please? JavaScript can also be used for clearform() method.

Comment: use basic html for this feature. before the </form> tag ends insert <input type="reset" value="Clear Data">. this will clear all field texts within the <form> tag. avoid JavaScript or additional code. this is already implemented in html.

Comment: @unixmiah that doesn't work because I'm echoing values into the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the elements by id and set the value attribute to empty string:

```
function clearform()
{
  document.getElementById('key_words').value = '';
  //same thing for other ids
}
```

For your `minimum_price` and `maximum_price` you need to add an `id` since you only have `name` right now.

Also in this case since you don't want to use HTML's standard reset functionality don't make the button type `reset`.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work. I've tried it before and I double checked it now. May be is it because I'm using php echo to print value on to the text field ?

Comment: @AnudeepKatragadda Its because you made the button type `reset`...just make it a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

It`s will be work for you:

```
<form action="sample.php" id="searchform" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="key_words" name="key_words" value="test1"style="width:377px;">
    <input type="text" name="minimum_price" value="test2">
    <input type="text" name="maximum_price" value="test3">

    <button type="reset" value="clear" onclick="clearform()">Clear</button>
</form>
<script>
    function clearform() {
        var form = document.getElementById("searchform");
        var textFields = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for(var i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
            textFields[i].setAttribute('value', '');
        }
    }
</script>
```